# Proving Randomness in a Card Game

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, games

I recently came across a card game that is played as follows.

For simplicity, assume that there are 4 players.

The deck of 52 cards is split evenly between them, leaving each player with 13 cards. Each player shuffles their cards and ends up with a random stack. The game proceeds by each player drawing the card at the top of *their* stack and adding it to an auxiliary stack consisting of previously drawn cards (this stack starts empty). Each round, a player gains all the cards in the auxiliary stack if and only if the last drawn card matches the card on top of the auxiliary stack - i.e two draws of the same value.

A player loses if they run out of cards and the last player standing is the winner.

For example, if the sequence of draws by A, B, C, D, A, B, C... is 2, 6, K, 3, K, 4, 4, then C gains all the cards played.

Since this game consists of a series of nested random processes, am I right in saying that the probability of a player winning is 1 / n in a game of 'n' players? If yes, how can I prove this randomness?

Comment: If you would consider a smaller version of the game, such as with a much smaller deck and fewer players, you will see that later players have an advantage over the first player.  It's hard to tell for sure, though, because you haven't completely described the game: what happens to the cards that are won?  Are they added to the player's stack?  If so, how?

Comment: The won cards are added to the bottom of the stack and the game is continued with the last player drawing the next card to a fresh, empty auxiliary stack

Comment: Are they added in the same order or shuffled?  I would re-invite you to contemplate a small game.  Consider, for instance, a deck with two aces and a game played between two players--A who starts and B who takes the next turn.  Do they have equal chances of $1/2$ to win?

Comment: I think I catch your idea! On average, the later players do indeed have an advantage. So if player 'A' always starts first, then the succeeding players have an advantage. Am I right in claiming that this purported advantage is nullified if the order of players is randomized too?

Comment: Yes, because when the order is randomized then (essentially by construction) everybody has the same chance of winning.  This would be the case even if it is *certain* that the first player loses.  This is why standard rules for card games require any privileged position, such as the dealer or the first hand dealt, to rotate in a systematic matter between rounds: that's a systematic method of equalizing the chances in the long run.